# Because Admob interstitial ads won't display?

Tags: java, android, admob

What is the error?Because admob interstital ads won't display?

```
 public  class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdListener {
        private InterstitialAd interstitial;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Create the interstitial
            interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "ca-app-pub-6xxxxxxxx/xxxxxx");
            // Create ad request
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
            // Begin loading your interstitial
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
            // Set Ad Listener to use the callbacks below
            interstitial.setAdListener(this);
        }
    public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("ads", "onReceiveAd");
        if (ad == interstitial) 
            interstitial.show();
    }
```

thanks i don't know because won't display

Answer (score 0):

Just follow below example

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

public class BannerExample extends Activity {

private InterstitialAd interstitial;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

// Create the interstitial.
     interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
     interstitial.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);

// Create ad request.
     AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

// Begin loading your interstitial.
     interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
}
//Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
    public void displayInterstitial() {

    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
      }
}
}
```

Comment: What i must insert MY_AD_UNIT_ID?

Comment: yes you must have to add your insert MY_AD_UNIT_ID like "ca-app-pub-6xxxxxxxx/xxxxxx"

Comment: thanks but when i insert this code for ads my apps don't open

Answer (score 0):

Your should add the `.build()` at the end of the creation of the `AdRequest`.

```
        // Create ad request
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest().build();
```